# MYSQL query with LIKE condition doesn't give right result

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I have database with different tables. I am trying to get emails from table Email if some conditions are met. One of condition is that name of advertisement from Ad table(given as parameter) has to contain text of suitable advertisement from SuitableAd table. I can't get this condition work(all other conditions works well).

```
@Query( "SELECT e.email FROM SuitableAd sad " +
        "JOIN sad.author a JOIN a.email e " +
        "WHERE :name LIKE '%sad.text%'" +
        " AND (:price BETWEEN sad.priceFrom AND priceTo) AND sad.category = :category")
List<String> findBySuitableAd(@Param("name") String name, @Param("price")BigDecimal price, @Param("category")
        String category);
```

Comment: Try switching the `WHERE` clause like this -> `"WHERE sad.text LIKE '%:name%'"`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
@Query( "SELECT e.email FROM SuitableAd sad " +
    "JOIN sad.author a JOIN a.email e " +
    "WHERE sad.text LIKE '%:name%'" +
    " AND (:price BETWEEN sad.priceFrom AND priceTo) AND sad.category = :category")
```

List findBySuitableAd(@Param("name") String name, @Param("price")BigDecimal price, @Param("category")
        String category);